# jquery shake effect with bootstrap issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a weird jquery effect using .effect("shake").My span which is the effect applied to moves in front of the element that contains it and when the effect is over it returns back to it's original position

```
<div id="menu_area">
<ul id="menu">
<?php


?>
<li><a href="<?=base_url()?>home">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#">All Products</a></li>
<li><a href="#" id="msgcart">Shopping Cart<span id='badgemessage' class='badge'><?=count($ses)?></span></a></li>
<li><a href="#">My Account</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Sign Up</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>
        <div id="search_form">
        <?=form_open_multipart(base_url().'products/search')?>
        <input type="text" name="pretrazi" id="search_input" placeholder="Search Products">
        <button type="submit" name="search" id="trazi"><img src="<?=base_url()?>images/search.png" width="20" height="17" id="searchslika"/></button>
        </form>
        </div>

</div>
```

css:

```
#menu_area{
width:1000px;
height:50px;

}
#menu{
margin:0;
padding:0;
line-height:35px;
list-style:none;
float:left;
position:relative;
}
#menu li{
display:block;
float:left;

}
#menu a{
text-decoration:none;
padding:8px;
margin:5px;
color:#444;
font-weight:bold;
}
```

bootstrap badge class:

```
.badge{
display:inline-block;
min-width:10px;
padding:3px 7px;
font-size:12px;
font-weight:700;
line-height:1;
color:#fff;
text-align:center;
white-space:nowrap;
background-color:#777;
border-radius:10px}
```

js:

```
$("#badgemessage").effect("shake",{distance:1,times:1});
```

Comment: Can you add a jsfiddle or jsbin reproducing your error?

Comment: @NateW  http://jsbin.com/civeluxuzi/1/edit?html,css,js,output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery adds a div wrapper to the item being manipulated does the `shake` effect and then removes the wrapping div. Your item was inline and so when the div wrapper was applied it was automatically it had `display: block;` by default.

Adding the following line of CSS fixes this default to allow it to be displayed as inline.

```
.ui-effects-wrapper {
  display:inline;
}
```

Working jsBin: http://jsbin.com/rijeluweje/2/edit

Comment: i'll check it ot when i get home and give you  the credits for it if it works for me